# I have delete /usr/bin/fastboot and now I cant reinstall fastboot tools

Tags: android-sdk

I have delete by mistake /usr/bin/fastboot by mistake and now I cant use fastboot tolls cause is nothing in /usr/bin/fastboot.

any idea what can I try?

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall fastboot`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=fastboot&searchon=contents

Comment: @KnudLarsen Would you mind making that a full answer to the question, as opposed to putting it in the comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following commands to recreate the file:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall fastboot
```

Comment: lovely ,now is result. Thanks for it.